# Eclipse doesn't show java source code

Tags: eclipse, attachment, java-6

I'm running java 1.6 in Eclipse on my Intel Mac. I'm using the 1.6.0 version under `System/Library/Frameworks` and set the default compiler to this in Eclipse.

How do I attach the source code?

First, I downloaded the 1.6 source from oracle, thinking I could attach that 'cause the installed 1.6 didn't have source.

When I click a java class to get the Source Code Editor, there are problems:

- first, the top line says `Compiled from File.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)`
- most important, when I attach the 1.6 source jar file, it gets an error:

  ```
  An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
  Unable to create resource org.eclipse.ui.internal.misc.ExternalProgramImageDescriptor@50417ba8
  ```

This also appears in the error log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.log.LogView
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
```

The Eclipse version is: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

When I click for installation details, I get:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Fetching children of _SELF_".
Registry Directory not available: /Users/rfrail/Downloads/eclipse 2/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry.
```

I'm running Eclipse from my Download directory (it's worked fine in the past); however, there are 2 folders for Eclipse:

- eclipse, and
- eclipse 2.

So that looks like a source of confusion right there. Eclipse operates fine otherwise.

Can you help, please?

Answer (score 0):

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ is your answer
it has an eclipse plugin which decompiles code in place

Comment: Thanx. I installed in eclipse, but when I try to associate "*.class" with the decompiler, I don't see that listed as an option in the
"Internal editors" list (same as at http://osdir.com/ml/webobjects-dev/2010-05/msg00345.html). So I dowloaded the jdk source and tried attaching it is the class file editor, but got no response. I see 2 JD-Eclipse jars in my eclipse plugins dir, and 1 in the features dir. JD-Eclipse also appears in the Available Software Sites, which I reloaded (then restarted eclipse). Can u help? Thanx

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I have 2 jars in plugins folder
"D:\opt\eclipse\plugins\jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3.jar"
"D:\opt\eclipse\plugins\jd.ide.eclipse.win32.x86_0.1.3.jar"
But no jar in features folder